# What page caused my 500 error from a JSP?

Tags: google-app-engine, jsp

Is there an easy way for me to identify which page caused a 500 error from a JSP 500 page?  I'm on Google AppEngine in Java. My /500 page is served by a jsp.  I've tried request.GetRequestURI() & request.GetRequestURL(), but it seems to just tell me I'm on mysite.com/500 which makes sense, but isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is stored in the request scope with the key `javax.servlet.error.request_uri`.

So, this should do:

```
<p>Request URI: ${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.request_uri']}</p>
```

Comment: I like this, but is there anyway to get at it from the java side of things? It would certainly be cleaner than writing some js to report on errors.

Comment: It's just `request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.request_uri")`.

Answer (score 0):

Login to the App Engine admin page and look through the logs for the 500 error.